# How do I get two columns from differnt tables and display data only if values less than 3 from second column?

Tags: sql

I need two columns (i.Inventory_Name II, p.Inventory_Quanity IP) from two different tables to display only if p.Inventory_Quanity IP < 3.

I tried the GROUP BY, HAVING, and COUNT cause but it only produces the same results of repeated data for each table.

**CREATES:**

```
create table II ( 
  Inventory_ID            number,  
  Inventory_Name          varchar2(50),    
  Inventory_Type          varchar2(50),
  constraint pk_II primary key (Inventory_ID) 
)

create table IP (
  Inventory_Price       varchar2(50),      
  Inventory_Quanity     number,
  Inventory_ID            number,
  constraint pk_IP primary key (Inventory_Quanity),   
  constraint fk_IP_id foreign key (Inventory_ID)
  references II (Inventory_ID)
)
```

**INSERTS:**

```
insert into II (Inventory_ID, Inventory_Type, Inventory_Name) values 
   (1,'Currency', 'Cash');
insert into II (Inventory_ID, Inventory_Type, Inventory_Name) values 
   (2,'Food', 'Apples');
insert into II (Inventory_ID, Inventory_Type, Inventory_Name) values 
   (3,'Currency', 'Electronic check');
insert into II (Inventory_ID, Inventory_Type, Inventory_Name) values 
   (4,'Food', 'Pizza');
insert into II (Inventory_ID, Inventory_Type, Inventory_Name) values 
   (5,'Cutlery', 'Plates');

insert into IP (Inventory_Price, Inventory_Quanity) values 
   ('$0', 60);
   insert into IP (Inventory_Price, Inventory_Quanity) values 
   ('$5', 5);
   insert into IP (Inventory_Price, Inventory_Quanity) values 
   ('+0', 80);
   insert into IP (Inventory_Price, Inventory_Quanity) values 
   ('$10', 2);
   insert into IP (Inventory_Price, Inventory_Quanity) values 
   ('$4', 1);
```

**DISPLAY:**

```
SELECT  i.Inventory_Name II, p.Inventory_Quanity IP FROM II i, IP p  
WHERE  p.Inventory_Quanity IN 
 (SELECT  p.Inventory_Quanity IP FROM IP p 
  where  p.Inventory_Quanity < 3GROUP BY  p.Inventory_Quanity HAVING COUNT ( p.Inventory_Quanity) < 3)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
II                    IP
Cash                  1
Cash                  2
Apples                1
Apples                2
Electronic check      1
Electronic check      2
Pizza                 1
Pizza                 2
Plates                1
Plates                2
```

Comment: Please show us your expected results for that sample data.

Comment: In your sample data, table `IP` is missing column `Inventory_ID`. How do we join the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0cf877ba30224eff6bf7781c3f51b0d2)**

```
SELECT  i.Inventory_Name II, sum(p.Inventory_Quanity) IP FROM II i inner join IP p 
on i.Inventory_ID=p.Inventory_ID
group by i.Inventory_Name
having sum(p.Inventory_Quanity)<3
```

OUTPUT:

```
II      IP
Pizza   2
Plates  1
```

Comment: I figured it out thank to you. I didn't Insert data into IP. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data is incomplete and you are not showing the expected results so it is hard to be sure what you want... I suspect that you are trying to pull out records in `ii` for which the total quantity in `ip` is less than 3.

I would phrase it as follows:

```
select 
    i.Inventory_Name,
    sum(p.Inventory_Quantity) Sum_Inventory_Quantity
from ii i
left join ip p on p.Inventory_ID = i.Inventory_ID
group by i.Inventory_ID, i.Inventory_Name
having coalesce(sum(p.Inventory_Quantity), 0) < 3
```

The `left join` avoids eliminating `ii` records that do not exist in `ip` (meaning they have no stock at all). Another thing to be careful about is to put the `Inventory_ID` in the `group by` clause (in case different records in `ii` have the same `Inventory_Name`).

Comment: Thank you, I see the error from when you said I had incomplete data

Comment: @HakeemThomas: welcome. I would suggest accepting the answer that was the most useful for you, by clicking the green check signe.This indicatest the community that your problem was solved, rewards the answerer, and rewards you too !